# How to find a link in an email and click on it? (Chrome / applescript / javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, jquery-selectors, applescript

What i've got part of code of outlook inbox letter:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody><tr>
<td height="2" colspan="3" style="line-height:2px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><**a href="https://www.facebook.com/confirmcontact.php?c=31085&amp;z=0&amp;gfid=AQALAirKRBiAw5qf1L4"** target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" style="color:#3B5998;text-decoration:none;" data-linkindex="2">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="text-align:center;background-color:#4C649B;display:block;border-collapse:collapse;border-radius:2px;padding:7px 16px 11px 16px;border:1px solid #344C80;">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/confirmcontact.php?c=31085&amp;z=0&amp;gfid=AQALAirKRBiAw5qf1L4" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" style="color:#3B5998;display:block;text-decoration:none;" data-linkindex="3">
<center><font size="3"><span style="color:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap;line-height:14px;">Подтвердить</span></font></center>
</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</a></td>
<td width="100%"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="32" colspan="3" style="line-height:32px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span>
```

How to find a link that starts with https://www.facebook.com/confirmcontact.php and click on it using apple script / javascript. Chrome.

I try this, but not yet very much.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell active tab of window 1
        execute javascript "document.querySelector('a[href=www.facebook.com/confirmcontact]').click()"
    end tell
end tell
```

Also got advice, but with error: **Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document**

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length;i++){
  if(links[i].match('www.facebook.com/confirmcontact')){
    links[i].click();
    break;//break the loop
  }
}
```

Need your help, colleagues.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't compile, your quotation marks around the facebook links shouldn't be doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, I'm no expert at Javascript but there were two problems with your code:

1. You didn't quote the link
2. `document.querySelector();` returns a list. You have to specify which element you want to target

The end product looks something like this:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell active tab of window 1
        execute javascript "document.querySelectorAll(\"a[href*='www.facebook.com/confirmcontact']\")[0].click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

<sub>The code posted above was tested on a MacBook Air 2019 on Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (x86_64)</sub>

Comment: gurkensaas, thanks for your advice. Please add ...href*='ww... to you code. Everything will work. And i will make it solved. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bro adding the star does nothing for me. I also can't find any documentation about the star, but it doesn't break the code. If you can explain it to me, I'll gladly add it.

Comment: = is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= is starts with
$= is ends with
*= is contains
~= is contains word

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you could find all links on a page using a query:`document.querySelectorAll("a"); or document.getElementsByTagName(a);`. After you've gotten the links you can iterate through the list/array and use `string1.match(string2);` where 'string1' is the href attribute of a link at position i of the array and 'string2' is the href you're looking for. After you have retrieved the link(the one that matches) just use `.click();` on it to trigger a click.
It should look something like this:

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length;i++){
  if(links[i].match('www.facebook.com/confirmcontact')){
    links[i].click();
    break;//break the loop
  }
}
```

Comment: In automator in applescript "conteiner" i put my part of code: tell application "Google Chrome"
 activate
end tell
delay 1 and your code i put in automators javascript "conteiner". Because i don't know how to activate current chrome tab in javascript. And there is an error: The action “Run JavaScript” encountered an error: “Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document”. Will you polish your code, please?